# biblatex: start reference numbering from 73 and not from 1

Tags: biblatex, numbering, citing

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Thesis.bib} 

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} 

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{thesis}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your example compilable (including documentclass).

Comment: And including some example entries from `Thesis.bib`.

Comment: ... some helpful information: a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)).

Answer (score 5):

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{%
  \ifinteger{#1}
    {\number\numexpr#1+72\relax}
    {#1}}
```

This simply takes the `labelnumber` generated by `biblatex` and adds 72, resulting in numbers starting from 73. The `\ifinteger` test is to make sure that we only try to do calculations with integers, in certain situations (`shorthand`) `labelnumber` might not actually be a number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{%
  \ifinteger{#1}
    {\number\numexpr#1+72\relax}
    {#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum,cicero,kant:kpv}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]