# Starting reference counter at =!1 does not work for multiple citations when using phys style

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-phys

I am using the solution given in the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401459/biblatex-start-reference-numbering-from-73-and-not-from-1/599239#599239) to start my reference counter at 0 instead of 1.
However when using the phys style I end up with the following problem:

This code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=phys]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{%
  \ifinteger{#1}
    {\number\numexpr#1-1\relax}
    {#1}}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{a}\cite{b}
\cite{a,b}
\end{document}
```

outputs

[image: wrong ref numbers]

instead of `[0][1][0,1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `\expanded` seems to fix the issue.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2020},
}
@article{b,
  author={W. Riter},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2020},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=phys]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{%
  \expanded{\ifinteger{#1}
    {\number\numexpr#1-1\relax}
    {#1}}}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{a}\cite{b}
\cite{a,b}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For a `numeric-comp`-based style things are slightly more tricky, because the `labelname` may not be a raw number, but a macro expanding to a number. That means we need to adjust the test `\ifinteger` to expand its argument.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=phys]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\pxifinteger}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \protected@edef\tempa{\endgroup%
    \blx@imc@ifinteger{#1}}%
  \tempa}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{%
  \pxifinteger{#1}
    {\number\numexpr#1-1\relax}
    {#1}}
\makeatother
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}

\cite{worman}

\cite{sigfridsson,worman}
\end{document}
```

[image: [0]//[1]//[0, 1]]