# How to resume bibliography `labelnumber` of `refsection` from the previous one?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

I am trying to write a syllabus for a course. However, the numbering of bibliography resets for each subsection. Is it possible to resume numbering from the previous `refsection`?

[image]

I think the this question [biblatex: start reference numbering from 73 and not from 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401459/biblatex-start-reference-numbering-from-73-and-not-from-1) may contain an answer by modifying  `labelnumber` field format.

My MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}

@book{nise2011control,
    title={Control Systems Engineering},
    author={Nise, Norman},
    edition={6},
    year={2011},
    publisher={John Wiley \& Sons}
}

@book{ogata2010modern,
    title={Modern Control Engineering},
    author={Ogata, Katsuhiko},
    edition={5},
    year={2010},
    publisher={Prentice Hall}
}

@book{williams2007linear,
    title={Linear State-Space Control Systems},
    author={Williams, Robert and Lawrence, Douglas},
    edition={1},
    year={2007},
    publisher={Wiley \& Sons}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt]{book}
    
    \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
    
    % ========== Citation packages ==========
% BEGIN_FOLD
    \usepackage[style=ext-numeric, maxnames=5, minnames=1]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{sample.bib}
    \setlength{\bibitemsep}{1.961pt}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\color{OrangeRed1}\textit{#1}}

% END_FOLD

\begin{document}

\section*{Textbook}

\begin{refsection}
    
    \nocite{nise2011control}
    
    \renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{}
    
    \printbibliography[heading=none]
    
\end{refsection}


\section*{Other References}

\begin{refsection}
    
    \nocite{ogata2010modern,williams2007linear}
    
    \renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{}
    
    \printbibliography[heading=none, resetnumbers=2]
    
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `refsection`s are by construction completely separate from each other. So they don't really lend themselves to these sort of things. At least in this example I cannot see the point of using `refsection`s anyway. Here a single `refsection` (or rather no `refsection` environment at all) together with `defernumbers` should suffice.

Comment: @moewe. Different books should be classified as either textbooks or references under a clear title. I posted an answer to the question, but hopefully someone may provide the ability to give the same result in one `refsection`

Comment: You could make the distinction with categories (`\DeclareBibliographyCategory` and friends) or keywords (`keywords` in the `.bib` file).

Comment: @moewe. How to sort references in the desired order (as cited in text), but also put entries of different categories under different main titles as shown in the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`refsection`s are by construction kept completely separate, so it is extremely painful to make them communicate with each other and have several `refsection`s influence each other.

For your use case simple split bibliography setup seems more attractive (note that for numeric split bibliographies you generally want `defernumbers`). If you prefer a dynamic approach where you decide in your `.tex` document which work belongs where, use categories

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage[style=ext-numeric, maxnames=5, minnames=1, defernumbers]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\color{OrangeRed1}\textit{#1}}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{textbooks}
\addtocategory{textbooks}{nise2011control}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{nise2011control,
  title     = {Control Systems Engineering},
  author    = {Nise, Norman},
  edition   = {6},
  year      = {2011},
  publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons},
}
@book{ogata2010modern,
  title     = {Modern Control Engineering},
  author    = {Ogata, Katsuhiko},
  edition   = {5},
  year      = {2010},
  publisher = {Prentice Hall},
}
@book{williams2007linear,
  title     = {Linear State-Space Control Systems},
  author    = {Williams, Robert and Lawrence, Douglas},
  edition   = {1},
  year      = {2007},
  publisher = {Wiley \& Sons},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{nise2011control,ogata2010modern,williams2007linear}

\printbibliography[category=textbooks, heading=subbibliography, title=Textbook]
\printbibliography[notcategory=textbooks, heading=subbibliography, title=Other References]
\end{document}
```

[image: Textbook [1] Norman Nise. Control Systems Engineering. 6th ed. John Wiley & Sons, 2011. Other References [2] Katsuhiko Ogata. Modern Control Engineering. 5th ed. Prentice Hall, 2010. [3] Robert Williams and Douglas Lawrence. Linear State-Space Control Systems. 1st ed. Wiley & Sons, 2007.]

If you prefer an approach where the categorisation is fixed in the `.bib` file, use keywords

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage[style=ext-numeric, maxnames=5, minnames=1, defernumbers]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\color{OrangeRed1}\textit{#1}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{nise2011control,
  title     = {Control Systems Engineering},
  author    = {Nise, Norman},
  edition   = {6},
  year      = {2011},
  publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons},
  keywords  = {textbook},
}
@book{ogata2010modern,
  title     = {Modern Control Engineering},
  author    = {Ogata, Katsuhiko},
  edition   = {5},
  year      = {2010},
  publisher = {Prentice Hall},
}
@book{williams2007linear,
  title     = {Linear State-Space Control Systems},
  author    = {Williams, Robert and Lawrence, Douglas},
  edition   = {1},
  year      = {2007},
  publisher = {Wiley \& Sons},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{nise2011control,ogata2010modern,williams2007linear}

\printbibliography[keyword=textbook, heading=subbibliography, title=Textbook]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=textbook, heading=subbibliography, title=Other References]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, we include the following

```
\newcounter{labelnumber}
\setcounter{labelnumber}{1}
\AtEveryBibitem{\addtocounter{labelnumber}{1}}
\AtBeginBibliography{\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\thelabelnumber}}
```

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}

@book{nise2011control,
    title={Control Systems Engineering},
    author={Nise, Norman},
    edition={6},
    year={2011},
    publisher={John Wiley \& Sons}
}

@book{ogata2010modern,
    title={Modern Control Engineering},
    author={Ogata, Katsuhiko},
    edition={5},
    year={2010},
    publisher={Prentice Hall}
}

@book{williams2007linear,
    title={Linear State-Space Control Systems},
    author={Williams, Robert and Lawrence, Douglas},
    edition={1},
    year={2007},
    publisher={Wiley \& Sons}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt]{book}
    
    \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
    
    % ========== Citation packages ==========
% BEGIN_FOLD
    \usepackage[style=ext-numeric, maxnames=5, minnames=1]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{sample.bib}
    
    \setlength{\bibitemsep}{1.961pt}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\color{OrangeRed1}\textit{#1}}
    
% END_FOLD

\newcounter{labelnumber}
\setcounter{labelnumber}{1}
\AtEveryBibitem{\addtocounter{labelnumber}{1}}
\AtBeginBibliography{\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\thelabelnumber}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Textbook}

\begin{refsection}
    
    \nocite{nise2011control}
    
    \renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{}
    
    \printbibliography[heading=none]
    
\end{refsection}

\section*{Other References}

\begin{refsection}
    
    \nocite{ogata2010modern,williams2007linear}
    
    \renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{}
    
    \printbibliography[heading=none, resetnumbers=2]
    
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```